# ¿Cómo podría guardar datos de cada proceso para una sola orden, y al mostrarlos en una tabla con SELECT y INNER JOIN, no se me repitan los registros?

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es el diseño de dos tablas de bases de datos que tengo desarrollada

[image: diseño de dos tablas de bases de datos]

SISTEMA DE PRODUCCIÓN DE CALZADOS

Al generar una orden, se almacenan los datos en la tabla "ordenes_detalles" inicializando con un proceso de producción: Ejemplo: Corte, Aparado, Armado, Acabado, adicional a esto almaceno el precio del proceso y precio total, ahora una vez finalizado un proceso "X" nuevamente quiero actualizar solo el proceso para la tabla "ordenes_detalles" y almacenarlo en la tabla detalles con un nuevo ID y que esta orden conserve como historial todos los procesos y precios para más adelante calcularlos. OJO no actualizar el mismo registro, sino generar un nuevo registro del proceso nuevo asignado a la misma orden.

Lo he logrado, pero al momento de mostrar las ordenes debería mostrar solamente la una orden con el mismo código y el proceso actualizado, pero me muestran las ordenes repetidas con el mismo código y lo que si es correcto con los datos del proceso y precios actualizados últimamente.

El otro problema es que al editar la orden para actualizar características de la tabla "ordenes_detalles" debería actualizar los datos de esta y en la tabla procesos, pero lo que sucede es que me pone los datos de la actualización para todos los procesos ya registrados.

Comment: Edita y agrega lo que llevas hecho al momento

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es mostrar una tabla en la que aparezcan todas las ordenes, unidas a los datos del ultimo proceso que se ha aplicado a cada orden.

Si es así, haz un INNER JOIN como ya habías hecho, eso te combina todas las ordenes con todos los procesos de una orden, por tanto te salen tantas ordenes como procesos se le hayan aplicado.

Para solventar esto, aplica un GROUP BY ORD_id para agrupar por ORD_id. Esto te mostrará una sola orden por cada orden existente. Pero puede que este segundo paso no te una con el ultimo proceso, para arreglarlo, aplica un ORDER BY PROC_id DESC.

Así tendrás una fusión de las 2 tablas en la que se muestra solamente un id por cada orden existente combinada con el id de proceso mas reciente aplicado a esa orden.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDENES_DETALLES
INNER JOIN PROCESOS ON ORDENES_DETALLES.PROC_id = PROCESOS.PROC_id
GROUP BY ORDENES_DETALLES.ORD_id
ORDER BY PROCESOS.PROC_id ASC
```

No he testeado el código porque no tengo las tablas ni datos, pero creo que si no es exactamente así, está bastante cerca de lo que quieres.

Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: Oh genial, muchas gracias. Había llegado a mostrar todos los datos de todas las órdenes, solo que al listarlas me mostraba una misma orden con 4 registros según los procesos. Ahora entiendo que me faltó el GROUP BY, voy a probar y te comento. Una última pregunta en el mismo listado es posible editar la orden con el último proceso? Por qué esto tampoco lo logré, al final resultó editando todos los procesos, dándoles los mismos datos...

Answer (score 0):

> Una última pregunta en el mismo listado es posible editar la orden con
>   el último proceso?

```
UPDATE ORDENES_DETALLES
SET campos que quieras actualizar
VALUES valores para esos campos
WHERE 
ORDENES_DETALLES.PROC_id = (SELECT MAX(ORDENES_DETALLES.PROC_id) FROM ORDENES_DETALLES WHERE ORDENES_DETALLES.ORD_id = orden_que_quieras_actualizar)
```

"Donde el id del proceso en la tabla de ordenes es el mayor para la orden ORD_id"